# Master page with a shell navigation and an additional singleton control that is always visible

Tags: maui, .net-maui.shell

I looking for something like a master page with two placeholders. The top placeholder contains the shell page with a navigation and a content page. And the lower placeholder contains a control that never changes after initialization. If a flyout item is clicked, only the content of the upper view changes.

The new Microsoft Media Player has a similar layout.

Which is the easiest way to create such a page, without having to customize a lot of renderers or handlers.

[image]

Comment: I think you can create a ControlTemplate and then just align it on the bottom of your screen. https://medium.com/@prateekrm/custom-navigation-bar-with-controltemplate-in-xamarin-forms-7f61e05ebc14

Comment: I need a outer page with an inner page. The inner page is the shell page

Comment: No clue what that means, have you ever seen this in any other applications? If yes can you show me some app that has this feature?

Comment: Only contentpages can create control templates. All pages that allow a navigation, flyoutpage, tabbedpage, etc. don't have that feature.

Comment: All of them internally use ContentPages, so i am not sure what do you mean

Comment: in uwp the shell page is an ordinary page with additional possibilities 

<Page>
 <winui:NavigationView/>
 <control:myusercontrol/>
<Page>

in xamarin, I extend the tabbedpage renderers for the desired feature. This was a lot of work. Now I'm looking for an easier way to do this

Comment: `I extend the tabbedpage renderers for the desired feature` Have you tried the [Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/?view=net-maui-7.0) in maui?

Comment: Yes i tried. I want to merge the UWP app and the Xamarin app into MAUI and support both, mobile and desktop, so this is a lot of work and a "little" complicated. So far I haven't found a suitable sample